Does a flat volatility skew imply a normal risk-neutral distribution?
Using Breeden-Litzenberger to convert a flat volatility skew to the risk-neutral distribution, would I obtain a normal risk-neutral distribution?
I use the formula
$$p(K) = \frac{n(d_2)}{K\sigma \sqrt{T-t}}$$
Therefore, if I obtain a normal risk-neutral distribution, I should obtain zero skewness and kurtosis if I calculate it off the risk-neutral probabilities.
However, when working with a flat volatility skew, if I extend the range of the moneyness bounds and obtain a longer range of risk-neutral probabilities, I get a more positive skew and much higher kurtosis for the new risk-neutral probability distribution.
Main Question: Is it correct to limit the moneyness bounds in this case (and what would be the correct bounds if there was one) if I wish to calculate the "correct" skewness and kurtosis of the risk-neutral distribution?
Please let me know if I have any conceptual errors and a link to any relevant articles would be very much appreciated as well.

Flat implied volatility, $\sigma(K,T)=\sigma(T) \forall K$ implies indeed a lognormal distribution for future price levels and hence a normal log-return distribution.

What does your $p(K)$ stand for? If it's the density then your expression for $p(K)$ is incorrect. Usually $p$ stands for density and $P$ for probability.

@Frido by density vs probability are you asking about PDF vs CDF?

Yes that's correct.

@Frido do you mind putting your comment as an answer? I would like to give you an upvote. I think yours might potentially be the answer as well. Do you mind providing an elaboration on your comment? Personally I do not see why using the density is incorrect as it does make sense to measure symmetry (and therefore skewness) from the PDF and the same explanation for kurtosis.

I'm not saying using the density (pdf) is incorrect. It is correct. What I mean is that $p(K) \neq N(d_2)/ K \sigma\sqrt{\tau}$, if in your notation $p(K)$ means the pdf. It is actually $p(K) = n(d_2)/ K \sigma\sqrt{\tau}$ where $n(x) = \frac{d}{dx} N(x)$. Does this clarify?

Ah yes, I think I was confused. I made the changes in the question. Thanks.
